# How do I make to creat a circle of radius equals to 1/\sqrt{5}?

Tags: geometry, latex, draw, calculus

The image that I want to do.

[image: Expectitive image]

[image: Image already created]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \tkzDefPoints{-4/0/A, 4/0/B, 4/4/C, -4/4/D, 0/0/O}
         \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
         \draw [pattern={hatch[hatch size=10pt, hatch linewidth=.4pt, hatch angle=15]}, pattern color=black]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
         \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) 
         \tkzGetPoint{E}
         \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) 
         \tkzGetPoint{F}
         \tkzDefMidPoint(C,D) 
         \tkzGetPoint{G}
         \tkzDefMidPoint(D,A) 
         \tkzGetPoint{H}
         \tkzFillPolygon(E,F,G,H)
         %\tkzDrawCircle                          Uncomment this part.
         %\tkzLabelPoints[auto](A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
```

Left a circle of radius of `\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}`.

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre] that contains all packages and/or libraries necessary to compile your code?

Comment: Yes, Samcarter is right, impossible to run your code without any header :(